# Sql Server - BIG DATA (horizontal scaling table)

Tags: azure-sql-database, query-performance, query-tuning

everyone.

I have a table called "Files" that has almost 100 million of rows.

My question is how can I improve my performance when try to search into this table. Actually, I'm using "FullText Index" to search on it.

One of the ideas was to split my main table in another equivalent tables (Horizontally Scaling Table), I guess this is the name of this technique.

If there is a better approach, please let me know. Any other suggestion would help a lot.

Thanks, everybody.

NOTE: I've already created "Indexes" using "SQL SERVER Execution Plan".

Comment: Note that "big data" is relative.  We have a few tables with about 5 billion rows.  Performance is maintained with indexes, query tuning, and very, very good hardware.  If there are specific performance issues, please include the query, the query plan, the table definition, and which indexes exist.

Comment: Please add some DDL, indexes, sample data and sample queries so people can help you.